# Get object property name as a string

Tags: javascript, string, object, properties

Is it possible to get the object property name as a string

```
person = {};
person.first_name = 'Jack';
person.last_name = 'Trades';
person.address = {};
person.address.street = 'Factory 1';
person.address.country = 'USA';
```

I'd like to use it like this:

```
var pn = propName( person.address.country ); // should return 'country' or 'person.address.country'
var pn = propName( person.first_name );      // should return 'first_name' or 'person.first_name'
```

**NOTE**: this code is exactly what I'm looking for. I understand it sounds even stupid, but it's not.

This is what I want to do with it.

HTML

```
person = {};
person.id_first_name = 'Jack';
person.id_last_name = 'Trades';
person.address = {};
person.address.id_address = 'Factory 1';
person.address.id_country = 'USA';


extPort.postMessage
(
  {
    message : MSG_ACTION,
    propName( person.first_name ): person.first_name
  }
};
```

----------------------**ANSWER**-----------------------

Got it thanks to ibu. He pointed the right way and I used a recursive function

```
var res = '';

function propName(prop, value) {
    for (var i in prop) {
        if (typeof prop[i] == 'object') {
            if (propName(prop[i], value)) {
                return res;
            }
        } else {
            if (prop[i] == value) {
                res = i;
                return res;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

var pn = propName(person, person.first_name); // returns 'first_name'
var pn = propName(person, person.address.country); // returns 'country'
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/iyabal/1/edit

Comment: I'm confused... why do you want the property name to return the same thing you fed it?  You already know the property name then...  If you're looking for a way to iterate through properties, you can use the bracket notation and loop through the keys, as properties are also hash indices

Comment: You need to also pass a reference to the object into the function.

Comment: Not automatically. The string referenced by `country` property doesn't know anything about the `address` object, and the object referenced by the `address` property doesn't know anything about the `person` object.

Comment: I understand this can be confusing, but that is exactly what I need. I need the property name as a string tough

Comment: so you actually mean var pn = propName("USA");

Comment: I'd love to help, but jsFiddle is currently unresponsive `-.-`

Comment: no. the code I posted is what I need. basically, the prop name is the ID of the page element and I want to get it to use it.

Comment: You need to explicitly pass them as separate values.

Comment: You want to use the ID to get the prop, or the prop to get the ID?

Comment: @Šime CodePen.io is better than jsFiddle anyway ;)

Comment: You really need to clarify your question, maybe add the html sample. Look at the answers, 4 people have 4 different interpretations!!!

Comment: Your code sample won't work as you're actually just passing the value of that property, not some reference to the property. Your first example would pass 'USA' to the function which is not useful for your desired result.

Comment: Do you want to do this just because you like the coding style, or are you working wtih some existing unchangeable code that you need to use this way?  What are your constraints?

Comment: And http://jsbin.com/iyabal/2/edit shows the flaw with this approach.

Comment: -1 Sorry, your code is really a bad practice. See this example: http://jsbin.com/iyabal/4/edit ... and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nestor_Burma as a reference ;-)

Comment: yes, you are both right and I have doped this line of thinking. I'm sending an array as a parameter now, and it's working fine. thanks anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Getting the object's property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260308/javascript-getting-the-objects-property-name)

Comment: This would be useful instead of passing strings around representing a object property name. You could then have static checking, refactoring or mangling.

Comment: [automatic name property in a created object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43127618/6452210)

Comment: [automatic name property for a created object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43127618/6452210)
you could have a look at that example.. ;)

Comment: Can you delete your answer out of the question please. If you want to answer your own question post an actual answer below so others can vote on it.

Comment: Tell me you want to use typescript without telling me you want to use typescript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, with a little change.

```
function propName(prop, value){
   for(var i in prop) {
       if (prop[i] == value){
            return i;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Now you can get the value like so:

```
 var pn = propName(person,person.first_name);
 // pn = "first_name";
```

**Note** I am not sure what it can be used for.

**Other Note** wont work very well with nested objects. but then again, see the first note.

Comment: This assumes that no two properties will have the same value in an object.

Comment: your function returns 'first_name' if you pass person.first_name but if you use person.address.street returns false. maybe using it recursively?

Answer (score 42):

I know a best practice that using [Object.keys(your_object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). It will parse to array property name for you. Example:

```
var person = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Cena', age: '30' };
var listPropertyNames = Object.keys(person); //["firstName", "lastName", "age"]
```

I hope this example is useful for you.

Comment: this does not answer the question, as it will return an array of the keys. the answer should return one string value

Comment: smh...
everything triet said but add .join()

Answer (score 35):

You can accomplish this by creating a mirror object that stores all the property names and call a property with an expression

**Javascript** version

```
var person = {};
person.firstname = 'Jack';
person.address = "123 Street";
person.child = { name: 'Example' };

function getPropertyName(obj, expression) {
    var res = {};
    Object.keys(obj).map(k => { res[k] = k; });
    return expression(res);
}

console.log(getPropertyName(person, o => o.address)); // 'address'
console.log(getPropertyName(person.child, o => o.name)); // 'name'
```

**Typescript** version (based on [@MadSkunk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66836940/2167309))

```
function getPropertyName<T extends object>(o: T, expression: (x: { [Property in keyof T]: string }) => string) {
  const res = {} as { [Property in keyof T]: string };
  Object.keys(o).map(k => res[k as keyof T] = k);
  return expression(res);
}

console.log(getPropertyName(obj, a => a.firstname)); // 'firstname'
console.log(getPropertyName(obj.child, a => a.name)); // 'name'
```

Comment: It is the best solution!

Comment: If you see warning about "no return value"; here is the modified version: **Object.keys(obj).map(k => { res[k] = () => k; return k;});**

Comment: FYI I've added a TypeScript version below if anyone's looking for one.

Answer (score 28):

If anyone's looking for a TypeScript version of MarsRobot's answer, try this:

```
function nameof<T>(obj: T, expression: (x: { [Property in keyof T]: () => string }) => () => string): string
{
    const res: { [Property in keyof T]: () => string } = {} as { [Property in keyof T]: () => string };

    Object.keys(obj).map(k => res[k as keyof T] = () => k);

    return expression(res)();
}
```

Usage:

```
const obj = { 
    property1: 'Jim',
    property2: 'Bloggs',
    property3: 'Bloggs',
    method: () => 'a string',
    child: { property4: 'child1' }
};

const test1 = nameof(obj, x => x.property1);
const test2 = nameof(obj, x => x.property2);
const test3 = nameof(obj, x => x.method);
const test4 = nameof(obj.child, x => x.property4);

console.log(test1);    // -> 'property1'
console.log(test2);    // -> 'property2'
console.log(test3);    // -> 'method'
console.log(test4);    // -> 'property4'
```

This version works even when objects have multiple properties with the same value (unlike some of the other answers above), and with editors like Visual Studio will provide intellisense for the property names when you get here: `nameof(obj, x => x.`

Comment: To get rid of the "No index signature with a parameter of type ...." error, you need to add `as keyof T` to `res[k]`. It would be `res[k as keyof T]`. Suggested edit queue is full else I'd add this to the answer myself.

Comment: I get an error: `TypeError: expression(...) is not a function`

Comment: It doesn't work if the property is nullable/optional (prop?) (gives the error said by @Olivier.B) but I don't know how to fix it :)

Comment: @CarloG it makes sense since that property may not be defined, therefore `Object.keys` wouldn't be able to retrieve it. Otherwise you may use `nameof(obj, a => a.optional!);`

Answer (score 14):

You can wrap your property in a function and then convert the function to a string and get the property out of it.

For example:

```
function getPropertyName(propertyFunction) {
    return /\.([^\.;]+);?\s*\}$/.exec(propertyFunction.toString())[1];
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var myObj = {
    myProperty: "testing"
};

getPropertyName(function() { myObj.myProperty; }); // myProperty
```

Beware that minifiers could break this.

**Edit:** I have created a compiler transform that works with babel and the typescript compiler (see [ts-nameof](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof)). This is a much more reliable than doing something at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

Using Proxy:

```js
var propName = ( obj ) => new Proxy(obj, {
    get(_, key) {
        return key;
    } 
});


var person = {};
person.first_name = 'Jack';
person.last_name = 'Trades';
person.address = {};
person.address.street = 'Factory 1';
person.address.country = 'USA';

console.log(propName(person).first_name);
console.log(propName(person.address).country);
```

Comment: Why does even this work `console.log(propName({}).first_name);`?

Comment: This fails when properties have same value.

Comment: It's working in JS V8 runtime, eg. substituting same values: person.last_name = person.first_name; and person.address.country = person.first_name; or that substitution using = 'Jack' instead of = person.first_name;

Comment: This answer is the best. It works. It's brief and clear. It's performant in speed/operations, in memory, in complexity (no iteration in the source code, no extra generations filtered by yet more operations, no risky exec()s), no extra objects. It uses Proxy for exactly the reflection Proxy is designed to do.

Answer (score 9):

I use the following in TypeScript. This way retains type-information and disallows selecting non-existing property keys.

```js
export function getPropertyName<T extends object>(obj: T, selector: (x: Record<keyof T, keyof T>) => keyof T): keyof T {
  const keyRecord = Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, key) => {
    const typedKey = key as keyof T
    res[typedKey] = typedKey
    return res
  }, {} as Record<keyof T, keyof T>)
  return selector(keyRecord)
}

const obj = {
  name: 'test',
  address: {
    street: 'test',
  }
}

console.log(getPropertyName(obj, (x) => x.name)) // name
console.log(getPropertyName(obj.address, (x) => x.street)) // street
```

Comment: Do you have a simple example how to use this method?

Answer (score 6):

I like one liners, here's a generic solution:

```
const propName = (obj,type) => Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === type)

propName(person, person.age)
```

Comment: this will give a wrong result in case the value of 2 keys are the same. ex:
`person = {old: 25, name:'John', age: 25};
propName(person, person.age); // return "old"`

Answer (score 3):

Following up on @David Sherret's answer with ES6 it can be made super simple:

```
propName = f => /\.([^\.;]+);?\s*\}$/.exec(f.toString())[1]
let prop = propName(() => {obj.name}); // myProperty
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer it clean and simple like this:

```
var obj = {
  sessionId: 123,
  branchId: 456,
  seasonId: 789
};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for (var i in keys) {
  console.log(keys[i]); //output of keys as string
}
```

Comment: And how do you get a specific key?

Comment: Why shoult Object.keys return a specific key? The point from that question was, to get the key of an object as a string!? Or not? I‘m confused now...

Comment: Yes, but you iterate over ALL keys. There is no chance getting a specific property name with your solution.

Comment: Ah, I got it! No, my solution is only for all keys, you‘re right. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a namespacing method for the object. The method will need to mutate the object so that the strings becomes an object instead to hold two properties, a `value` and a `_namespace`.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y8p/1/**

```
var namespace = function(root, name) {
    root._namespace = name;
    function ns(obj) {
        for( var i in obj ) {
            var a = obj._namespace.split('.')
            if ( a.length ) {
                a.push(i);
            }
            if( typeof obj[i] == 'object' ) {
                obj[i]._namespace = a.join('.');
                ns(obj[i]);
                return;
            }
            if( typeof obj[i] == 'string' ) {
                var str = obj[i].toString();
                obj[i] = {
                    _namespace: a.join('.'),
                    value: str
                };
            }
        }
    }
    ns(root);
};

namespace(person, 'person');

console.log(person.address.street._namespace) // person.address.street
console.log(person.address.street.value) // 'Factory 1'
```

So now you can do:

```
var o = { message: MSG_ACTION };
o[ person.first_name._namespace ] = person.first_name.value;

extPort.postMessage(o);
```

Comment: I was fascinated by this answer so I started hacking away at it to try and find a cleaner approach.  here is what I've come up with so far, what do you think: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y8p/17/

Comment: @JasonSperske nice, but it’s not recursive so it only works 3 levels deep: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y8p/18/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y8p/22/  try it now :)  There are still larger problems, like it takes all values and casts them to strings, but this is a fun bit of code to play with

Answer (score 0):

I am in same situation.

Here is thy way to get it done using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findKey) or [UnderScore](http://underscorejs.org/#findKey) library, with one limitation of value to be unique:

```
var myObject = {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': 3
}
_.findKey(myObject, function( curValue ) { return myObject.a === curValue });
```

Plain JavaScript

```
function getPropAsString( source, value ){
    var keys = Object.keys( source );

    var curIndex,
        total,
        foundKey;

    for(curIndex = 0, total = keys.length; curIndex < total; curIndex++){
        var curKey = keys[ curIndex ];
        if ( source[ curKey ] === value ){
            foundKey = curKey;
            break;
        }
    }

    return foundKey;
}

var myObject = {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': 3
}
getPropAsString( myObject, myObject.a )
```

But, I would prefer to fix the code as solution. An example:

```
var myObject = {
'a': {key:'a', value:1},
'b': {key:'b', value:2},
'c': {key:'c', value:3}
}

console.log( myObject.a.key )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but I took a completely different approach, so I will throw in my approach and see what the community thinks.

I used [`Function.prototype.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) to do what I want.
my properties are functions that when called return the value of the property, and I can get the name of the property (which is a function) using `.name`

Here is an example:

```
person = {
    firstName(){
        return 'John';
    },
    address(){
        return '123 street'
    }
}

person.firstName.name // 'firstName'
person.address.name // 'address'
```

**Note:**
you can't easily change the value of a property (e.g firstname) at run time in this case.
you would need to create a function (`.name` would be anonymous in this case) and this function would return a new named function which return the new value:

```
// note the () at the end     
person.firstName = new Function('', 'return function firstName(){return "johny"}')(); 
person.firstName.name ; // 'firstName' 
person.firstName(); // 'johny'
```

Comment: @Please_Dont_Bully_Me_SO_Lords, Hence the sentence: "my properties are functions that when called return the value of the property"

Comment: and that's why I made it clear in my answer: 1- I am taking a different approach, 2- my properties are functions, 3- I have a note about how you should update the value of a property. By no means I am suggesting that this is the best approach, I am just proposing a way to do what OP wants to do. In his example it is a string because he is using plain attributes, in my approach I am wrapping them in functions. OP can use my answer to add wrapper around his attributes. My attributes are functions syntactically, yes. but, semantically, my attributes are the result of the function call,

Comment: @Please_Dont_Bully_Me_SO_Lords, if you see anyway this answer can be improved, please be my guest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Improved Solution for TypeScript using PROXY from Isk1n solution:

```js
//get property name
export function getPropertyName<T>(obj: any): T {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(_, key) {
      return key;
    }
  });
}
```

and usage:

```js
sampleItem: TestClass = new TestClass();
getPropertyName<TestClass>(this.sampleItem).LayoutVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

`selectorToPropertyPath` converts any property selector callback into an array of properties.

```js
const target = {};

const handler = (parents = []) => ({
    get: (target, property) => {
        if (property in target) {
            return target[property];
        }
        
        target[property] = new Proxy({
            __path: [...parents, property],
        }, handler([...parents, property]));
        
        return target[property];
    },
});

const proxy = new Proxy(target, handler());

const selectorToPropertyPath = (selector) =>
    selector(proxy).__path;


// Usage:
const accessId = (data) => data.id;
const accessGroupId = (data) => data.group.id;
const accessRandomProperties = (data) => data['one'].two['three'].four['five'];

console.log(selectorToPropertyPath(accessId));
console.log(selectorToPropertyPath(accessGroupId));
console.log(selectorToPropertyPath(accessRandomProperties));


// NOTE: Property `__path` is reserved to store path info. This will return the correct path:
console.log(selectorToPropertyPath(data => data.__path));
// ...however, this will return invalid path:
console.log(selectorToPropertyPath(data => data.__path.__path));
```

`TypeScript` implementation:

```typescript
type Target = {
    [key: string | symbol]: Target;
} & { __path?: (string | symbol)[] };

const target: Target = {};

const handler: (parens?: (string | symbol)[]) => ProxyHandler<typeof target> = (parents = []) => ({
    get: (target, property) => {
        if (property in target) {
            return target[property];
        }

        target[property] = new Proxy({
            __path: [...parents, property],
        } as Target, handler([...parents, property]));

        return target[property];
    },
});

const proxy = new Proxy(target, handler());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to solve for each depth of the object.

Here's a solution using the string from `Object.keys()`

```js
const PersonKeyStrings = Object.keys(Person).reduce((mem, keySt) => 
  (mem[keySt] = keySt, mem), {})

let first_name_str = PersonKeyStrings.first_name
let first_name_value = Person[first_name_str]
```

Answer (score -2):

No, it's not possible.

Imagine this:

```
person.age = 42;
person.favoriteNumber = 42;

var pn = propName(person.age)
// == propName(42)
// == propName(person.favoriteNumber);
```

The reference to the property name is simply lost in that process.