# Getting the class name of an Enum in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some enums in my Typescript application and I use code similar to this to get the string value to display in the application:

```
enum Color{ RED, BLUE, GREEN};

document.write( "The string for Red is: " + Color[Color.RED] );
```

However, the string value is usually more along the lines of a database key or some other server related string rather than a nicely formatted string fit for display to the user.
To get round this I want to load localised property files that use the string value of an enum to look up a nicely formatted string to display in the application. The file might look like this:

```
Color.properties:
RED=The color is red
BLUE=The color is blue
GREEN=The color is green
```

I am confident that I can load this file and parse the contents to populate some lookup for later display in the application but I am not sure about how to know which property file to load.
For the following enums

```
Color
Shape
Animal
```

I will have the following property files:

```
Color.properties
Shape.properties
Animal.properties
```

My question is: Is there any way of getting the string "Color" from the run time javascript definition of Color?
The Typescript code for Color gets transpiled into:

```
var Color;
(function (Color) {
    Color[Color["RED"] = 0] = "RED";
    Color[Color["BLUE"] = 1] = "BLUE";
    Color[Color["GREEN"] = 2] = "GREEN";
})(Color || (Color = {}));
```

I don't think that I can get the String Color out of that in any easy way. I assume that I am just going to have to use switch expression to lookup the name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there's nothing built into the language that allows you to get the name of an enum at runtime.

However, I used the following method to do it:

```
namespace MyEnums {

    export enum Color { RED, BLUE, GREEN };

    export enum Shape { ROUND, SQUARE };

    export function getName(enumObj: any): string {

        for (let name in MyEnums) {
            if ( MyEnums[name] === enumObj && MyEnums.hasOwnProperty(name) ) {
                return name;
            }
        }

        return undefined;
    }
}

const Color = MyEnums.Color;

var name = MyEnums.getName(Color);
```

Although, I ended up refactoring my code so I wouldn't need to get the names in the end.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to make the file you store your strings in a TypeScript file and then use the actual enum—`Color`—to do the mapping.

With that said...

> Is there any way of getting the string "Color" from the run time javascript definition of Color?

A reliable solution is to use something like [ts-nameof](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof).

Alternatively, you can use a similar trick that's outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32542368/188246):

```
function getVariableName(variableFunction: () => any) {
    return /\s([^\s;]+);?\s*\}$/.exec(variableFunction.toString())[1];
}

var variableName = getVariableName(() => Color); // returns string "Color"
```

This wraps Color in a function then calls `.toString()` on that function. Using that string it will extract out only the name provided.

Just make sure you test to see if this works after being minified.