# Angular 2 - Dynamic Variables in ngModel

Tags: angular

How to use dynamic variables in ngModel?

I am trying to use the code below but the following error appears:

```
<div *ngFor="let num of ['1','2','3']; let i=index">
    <input id="qtd{{num}}" [(ngModel)]="qtd{{num}}" type="text"/>
</div>
```

**Erro**

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}})`

Comment: Use an array, and use `qtd[num]`.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Define array in component and keep pushing in it.

```
export class AppComponent {
    qtd:any[] = {};
}
```

Then, update your template like

```
<div *ngFor="let num of ['1','2','3']; let i=index">
    <input id="qtd{{num}}" [(ngModel)]="qtd[num]" type="text"/>
</div>

{{ qtd | json}}
```

In this all your dynamic models will be in **qtd** array

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lFjbkRQ2bniq2leOMus1)**

Hope that helps!

Comment: it works very well! Thank you! I've been looking for the right answer for a few hours! Thanks! :)

Comment: i got bug when i used `{}`. so i used `qtd:any[] = [];`

Comment: is there a possibility to get typesafety on this?

Comment: I found what I was looking for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547583/safe-way-to-extract-property-names . Something like `nameof<MyThing>("myProperty")` .

Comment: I can add dynamic model value but i can't change that dynamic value. do you have any idea?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari, will you show your code so we know what exactly you meant

Comment: @AshokShah I got answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558029/ionic3-how-to-update-value-of-dynamic-ngmodel?noredirect=1#comment97818498_55558029

Answer (score 13):

Let's say you have the following component

```
export class AppComponent {
  qtd1 = 'qtd1';
  qtd2 = 'qtd2';
  qtd3 = 'qtd3';
}
```

Then your template might look like:

```
<div *ngFor="let num of ['1','2','3']; let i=index">
  <input id="qtd{{num}}" [(ngModel)]="this['qtd' + num]" type="text"/>
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/F5NpBOAesy0udwRW9wDk?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks yurzui.It is useful for me.can i use pipe with this "this['qtd' + num]" dynamic variable .if means pls help me

Comment: @kamalav Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular/39643180#39643180

Comment: I used pipes in normal variable.But here(in dynamic variable) it gives error.thats y I am asking u

Comment: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ] at column 55 in [let abstract of this[res.Id | replaceSpecialChar +'string'];

Comment: @kamalav Can you reproduce it on stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way if you want, in case you want an id matching the index.

```
<div *ngFor="let num of ['1','2','3']; let i=index">
    <input 
     [attr.id]="'qtd'+i"
    type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works fine in my case:

```
   export class AppComponent {
    qtd:any[] = {};
   }
```

In html i used index instead of value (num):

```
<div *ngFor="let num of ['1','2','3']; let i=index">
    <input id="qtd[i]" [(ngModel)]="qtd[i]" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

We would mostly need dynamic ngModel in the case of dynamic text box creation.

*In your ts file*

```
 export class AppComponent {
 public selectedBranch: any[] = [0];
 public selectedShiftNameTime: any[] = [0];
 public CustomDates: any[] = [0];
}
```

*your HTML file (Template)*

```
 <table class="table" style="padding: 20px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-2">Employee Name</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">Branch</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">Shift Type</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">Custom Dates</td>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let emp of Empdata">
            <td>
                <label>
                    {{emp.name}}
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control rounded-0"  id="selectedBranch{{emp.EmployeeInfoId}}"  >
                    <option value='0'>--Select--</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let branch of Branchdata" [value]=branch.BranchId>
                            {{branch.BranchName}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>

                <select class="form-control rounded-0"  id="selectedShiftNameTime{{emp.EmployeeInfoId}}"  >
                        <option value='0'>--Select--</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let shifType of ShiftTypedata" [value]=shifType.ShiftTypeId>
                                {{shifType.ShiftName}}
                        </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>

                <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select Custom Dates'" [data]="dropdownList" id="CustomDates{{emp.EmployeeInfoId}}" [(ngModel)]="CustomDates[emp.EmployeeInfoId]"
                    [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
                </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" >
                <button type="button" (click)='submit()' >Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```