# Ionic3 - How to update value of dynamic ngModel?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 framework. How to change value of ngModel? I want to toggle all ion-toggle programmatically.

**component**:

```
allRecs:any; 
constructor(){
  this.allRecs = [
    {
      label: "label 1", 
      model : "model1"
    }, 
    {
      label: "label 2", 
      model : "model2"
    }, 
    {
      label: "label 3", 
      model : "model3"
    }
  ]
}

public toggle(flag:boolean){
  console.log(flag);
}
```

**html**:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let x of allRecs">
   <ion-label> {{x.label}} </ion-label>
   <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="x.model" (ionChange)="toggle(x.model)" item-end>
   </ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

Can anyone has idea?

Comment: ion-toggle needs a boolean value, if you bind it a boolean it will work, for e.g ```model : false```.

Comment: @FatemeFazli yes you are right but how can i update it dynamically?

Comment: you can update your allRecs by adding another attr for e.g ```{
      label: "label 3", 
      model : "model3",
      value: false
    }``` then change the ngModel to x.value .

Comment: you're welcome, i will add it as an answer.

Comment: @FatemeFazli can we connect somewhere if you dont mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191395/discussion-between-fateme-fazli-and-khurshid-ansari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ion-toggle needs a boolean value, if you bind it to a boolean, it will work.
in your allRecs model attribute is string so initial value not effects on ion-toggle and can't change it. so x.model should be boolean or add a new boolean attribute for e.g value to set it for ngModel:

```
constructor(){
  this.allRecs = [
    {
      label: "label 1", 
      value: false
    }, 
    {
      label: "label 2", 
      value: false
    }, 
    {
      label: "label 3", 
      value: true
    }
  ]
} 

toggle(flag:boolean){
    for(let i=0;i<this.allRecs.length;i++){
        this.allRecs[i].value = flag; 
    }
}
```

in html:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let x of allRecs">
   <ion-label> {{x.label}} </ion-label>
   <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="x.value" (ionChange)="toggle(x.value)" item-end>
   </ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do like the example above, but needs some improvement like follows.

```javascript
constructor(){
  this.allRecs = [
    {
      id: 1, //add this line
      label: "label 1", 
      value: false
    }, 
    {
      id: 2, //add this line
      label: "label 2", 
      value: false
    }, 
    {
      id: 3, //add this line
      label: "label 3", 
      value: true
    }
  ]
} 

/*
* in this method added new parameter `id: number`
*/ 
toggle(id: number, flag:boolean) {
    for(let i=0;i<this.allRecs.length;i++) {
        //check if the current record has the same id
        if (this.allRecs[i].id == id) {
           this.allRecs[i].value = flag; 
        }
    }
}
```

in html:

```html
<!-- added new parameter `x.id` when occurs `ionChange` event calling toggle method -->
<ion-item *ngFor="let x of allRecs">
    <ion-label> {{x.label}} </ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="x.value" (ionChange)="toggle(x.id, x.value)" item-end>
    </ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: can you hight light with bold what you improved in your code ?