# extract property names in a strongly typed way

Tags: typescript, metaprogramming, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The following answer addresses how to safely extract property names from a type. What this answer accomplishes is that, indeed, if there is a mistyping you get a compile-time error, not a runtime error:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516869/274677

However, the property names extracted in this manner are typed as `string`, not as a string literal (with the name of the actual property). This has some limiting implications, e.g. it does not allow them to be used with the `Omit` utility type.

[This typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE52QU1VAngeWAB4AVAPgAowBDAW0wC5EBrTXOYREgSkQG8AUIkSpMUEKiQ16AbgEBfAQLxZEAQQBCiALz9qTMCFoAjbABpExg0dOp5cgRAQBnKOp0p0WHAWKbKAOTUAdwOAPQAVEIRwgBycADuiM7UuIhQABbUbgCSiAnUYG5QcIhOYK4g0OkZmIjAcAA2jYkwYADm6bhYDNHRwsIqdVq6fFaIhibYiogx-QB0i-kwmTV1AI4g1I0wwDAQ2fBImdmIeQVF6aXlrqhVbiuWaXC0K7AdiP0DyS91aBjYWCYZz1dC0RDUZYAE2wXSw80QAAM1IiyoUwHA3KZECBnJgofU4KgajBnF8BsgJMg4HifogEHUsiCShD2tQ2nC6pk6tI6hw1p4AT4Ic4mEEAv1omElENEBoAPrGXDyl6PXT4V5QIiaCzisjfAZhMKc%20mcBVKlWaxCkspE0TQRppf4Y8AQfEi-jjSa2RTKbrDRXK1VQABMHg1K21GgsQ35an1RpN-PNQc1YZtfF9AiAA) demonstrates the problem. Playground code pasted below for completeness purposes:

```
function propertyOf<T>(name: keyof T) {
  return name;
}

type AB = {a: number, b: number};

const A = propertyOf<AB>('a');

/*
 *  Now say that I want to constuct the following type:
 *
 *    type B = {b: number}
 * 
 * ... with the qualification that I want to construct it by omitting 
 *     some properties from a wider type. `A` cannot be used for this
 *     purpose so one has to again type the name of the property as: 'a'
 * 
 */

type B_by_omit = Omit<AB, 'a'>       // type of B_by_omit is correctly pronounced as {b: number}

type B_by_omit2 = Omit<AB, typeof A> // type of B_by_omit2 is {}
```

Is there way to safely extract property names from a type and have them typed as string literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `propertyOf` to return the string literal type `"a"` when you pass `"a"` to it, we will need to add another generic type `K` to the function which will be inferred by the parameter `name`.

```
// this does not work. see below
function propertyOf<T, K extends keyof T>(name: K): K {
  return name;
}
```

But this does **not** work. The problem is that TypeScript [does not support partial type inference yet](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242). So we can't explicitly provide a type for `T` while having `K` automatically inferred.

To achieve something similar, we could use currying instead.

```
function propertyOf<T>() {
  return <K extends keyof T>(name: K) => name;
}
```

The function would now be called like this:

```
const A = propertyOf<AB>()("a");
//    ^? const A: "a"
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE52QU1VAngeWAB4AVAPgAoBKRAbwChFFVMoRUkiBpRTADyiYwAEwDOiANaZccYInIUwAQwC2mAFyIuNALxlEytQG56AX3r08WRAEEAQoh11ESzWBAqARtgA0iT24e3qiIpib0EAiiULaOKOhYOATE9pRUFABEShlU4QD0AFSMBUwAcnAA7oiiSriIUAAWSjEAkogVSmAxUHCIkWDRIND1DZiIwHAANpOVMGAA5vW4WOrFxUxMVmMOTrQBBkHY5ogl6wB0F%200wjSNjAI4gSpMwwDAQzfBIjc2IbR1d9V6-WiqCGMWu-jqcBU11gC0Q6w21WhYzQGGwsEw4mA6BULiuwmwSywZ0QAAMbGS%20p0wHAYt5ECBRJhhOM4CFGjBRIiNsh2Mg4MzkYgEGMmuIei55ko5sSxo0xoYxrJbvF0UkXKJNAByJTa9bFPIWLaIOwAfU8uDN0IhTnwMKgRHsfl12v0SKYeTycpFcnNlutDsQXL67JY0EmdTRtPAEBZmro%203cXiOxuW2wtVptUAATHF7dcnXY-FsVTZ9F6fSr-VmHXmQ7RzBYgA)