# How can I get the name of a property from inside an object to create a new property name?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I know there are a few other posts on this topic, but they don't seem to address my issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612006/get-object-property-name-as-a-string).

I want to be able to dynamically get the name of a specific property in an object so that I can use it to create a new property name inside another object. For example, I would get the property name `startMin` from `foo` (as in my code below) and then add text to the end of it (like `startMin + Suffix`) to create a new property name. How can I do this?

A related note: I've already figured out how to get the property value with `foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]]`. Though this works, I'm not sure why `Object.keys` gets the property value in this case since the examples I've found suggest `Object.keys` is supposed to get the property name not the property value. I'd love to know why?

I have included the pusdo code `foo[Object.returnObjectName(foo)[0]] + 'Cal'` where I want the name to be dynamically created. It doesn't work, of course.

```js
var foo = {
  startMin: 1000
};

var fooResults = {
  // the property name here is psudo code 
  foo[Object.returnObjectName(foo)[0]] + 'Cal': foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]]
}

console.log('startMinCal: ' + fooResults.startMinCal) // This should log "1000" but won't until the object name inside `fooResults` is created correctly.

// 
console.log(Object.keys(foo)); // I believe this gests the property name, but it exists inside an array, so won't work as a new property name 
console.log(foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]]); // this gets the property value as expected.
```

UPDATED WORKING CODE:

```js
var foo = {
  startMin: 1000,
  startMax: 3000
};

var fooResults = {
  [Object.keys(foo)[0] + 'Cal']: foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]],
  [Object.keys(foo)[1] + 'Cal']: foo[Object.keys(foo)[1]]
}

console.log('startMinCal: ' + fooResults.startMinCal)
console.log('startMaxCal: ' + fooResults.startMaxCal)
```

Comment: Not really sure what you try to achieve. This `(obj, suffix) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((ac, k) => ({ ...ac, [k+ suffix]: obj[k] }), {})` can take `{a: 1, b:2}` and `'x'` to create `{ax: 1, bx: 2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var foo = {
  startMin: 1000
};


//Object.keys return all the keys in an object passed as parameter

//here your wanted key is at first position
var key = Object.keys(foo)[0];

//get the value
var value = foo[key]

//append whatever suffix you want
key += 'Cal';



var fooResults = {
  //to use  content of variable as key of object put variable  in []   
  [key]: value
}


//another solution 
//create emtyy object 
var fooResults2 = {}

//use use variable name as index
fooResults2[key] = value


console.log('startMinCal: ' + fooResults.startMinCal) // This should log "1000" but won't until the object name inside `fooResults` is created correctly.

console.log('startMinCal: ' + fooResults2.startMinCal)
```

Comment: `Object.keys(foo)` return all the property names in foo object  as array......`Object.keys(foo)[0]` returns first of those property names....... and  thereby `foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]]` returns value of that property in foo object

Comment: This comment, in addition to your answer, helped a lot. Thanks! I made an update to my code to show the working version.