# How to get id of JSON objects in Java

Tags: java, json

I have previously used GSON, which automatically transfers the data as long as my custom object has a variable with the same name. However, this time, I'm also intrested in the name, or ID, of the object. The object only contains a single long. Example of how it looks:

```
{"1":123,
 "2":124,
 "4":125,
 "5":126,
 "6":127}
```

As you can see, the list don't necessarily contain all sequent IDs so I cannot just create a list. How would you solve the problem?

Comment: Why are the value strings where they can be JSON numbers?

Comment: @fge My bad, I updated the post.

Comment: @user3600338 Why don't you use a simple `Map` to deserialise the JSON and then iterate over it?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat Excactly!

Comment: @DanailAlexiev I do not have any knowledge about Maps, but I guess I know what to look into now :)

Comment: @user3600338 Ow, didn't expected it to be that simple so I removed my comment. Check that out then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260308/getting-the-objects-property-name
But as I'm reading things again, I'm pretty sure you want these values on Java code, not JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deserializing to a specific custom object, just deserialize to `Map<String, Integer>`:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Integer>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Integer> result = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jython](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython-standalone/2.7.0):

```
import json
json_data = json.loads(your_string_above)
ids = json_data.keys()
# ids now contains [u'1', u'2', u'4', u'5', u'6']
```

Hope that helps.