# How to differentiate between property and value passed in a function together

Tags: javascript, object, hasownproperty

I need to check if objects in an array to see if they include a property, and if so, whether the properties' values match.

The property and value are given together in the function call:

```
whatIsInAName(
    [
        { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, 
        { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, 
        { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }
    ], 
    { last: "Capulet" }); //Property: last, value: Capulet.
```

The function definition:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
```

I couldn't find anyway to separate the property from the value (they are both inside of `source`) so that I can first check if the property exists with `hasOwnProperty` and if so, then compare the values.

Comment: In your real code, the property name in `source` (`last`) is unknown to you?

Comment: You can get all of the properties of any object using `Object.keys()`, as indicated by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4260308/215552)...

Comment: Use a `for-in` loop.

Comment: @Teemu: Yes, it is unknown. That's the problem. I know how to check whether one of the array's object has a certain property name or no- But I don't know how to separate `last` from `Capulet` in `source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). It returns an array of property names of the object.

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source));
// ['last']
```