# how to get json object titles

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list

I'm a new programmer , I know how to use dictionary/JSON to get the value of whatever you want like for example `var x = {"name":jack,"age":20};

then x.name = jack`

but what if I've a table that has been imported through an unknown EXCEL file and I just want to know the title of each column , how can i do that ?

for example

```
Var table = [{"id":0 , "name":jack,"age":25,"profession":student},{"id":1 , "name":nora,"age":22,"profession":student}]
```

i want to make a javascript function that can inform me with titles of each columns , the number of the columns 
how can i do that ?

Comment: do note `Var table =` is invalid syntax, and both `name:jack,` and `profession:student}` is likely wrong too, strings must be enclosed in delimiters

Comment: should `profession:student` be `profession:"student"` ?

Comment: i fixed it thanks , correct me if iam not wrong but `"profession":student` is the right syntax

Comment: Unless `student` is a variable, you are wrong :D Also, note that JavaScript, like most of the popular programming languages, is case-sensitive, and `Var` is not `var`. This is correct: `var table = [{"id":0 , "name":"jack","age":25,"profession":"student"},{"id":1 , "name":"nora","age":22,"profession":"student"}]`

Comment: You can validate a json online here : https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 3):

First of all, an object in JavaScript doesn't care if it was constructed out of JSON or not. So your object in JavaScript syntax will look like this:

```
const x = { name: 'jack', age: 20 };
```

If you now do `Object.keys(x)`, you will get this:

```
[ 'name', 'age' ]
```

And `Object.keys(table[0])` should be exactly what you want: the column names of your 'table'

```
[ 'name', 'age' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of the names of the properties of an object in javascript with this :

```
Object.keys();
```

Documentation here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Response of a similar question here :

[Getting the object's property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260308/getting-the-objects-property-name)

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(table[0])
```

will give you the keys of the first row; presumably the other rows will behave and follow the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over object keys:

```
for (var key in table[0]) {console.log(key);}
```

or (will work in most modern browsers):

```
Object.keys(table[0]).forEach(key => console.log(key));
```

Don't forget to check if "table" has elements

Also see [other possible options](https://hackernoon.com/5-techniques-to-iterate-over-javascript-object-entries-and-their-performance-6602dcb708a8)

Comment: This is not recommended. Try executing `Object.prototype.foo = "bar"` before running your code for a nice surprise. If you are using `for ... in` to iterate over object keys, almost always you'll want to test `.hasOwnProperty` to rule out intruders.

Comment: True. But I assume in this exact situation nothing is being overridden in Object.     Iterating in foreach is just faster and works in old IEs. Here are examples of all techniques: https://hackernoon.com/5-techniques-to-iterate-over-javascript-object-entries-and-their-performance-6602dcb708a8

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = Object.keys(objectname)
console.log(test)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck