# Assigning the name of an object obtained via an API to a variable

Tags: javascript, object

I need some assistance with capturing the name of an object in a variable and then using this variable in another API call. (I'm not sure if this is even possible?)

I'm trying to capture the name of a countries currency from one API then using this variable in another API call to get the exchange rate for that currency.

The result of the initial API call which holds the currency name is as follows:

```json
{
  "name": {
    "common": "United Kingdom",
    "official": "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
    "nativeName": {
      "eng": {
        "official": "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
        "common": "United Kingdom"
      }
    }
  },
  "tld": [".uk"],
  "cca2": "GB",
  "ccn3": "826",
  "cca3": "GBR",
  "cioc": "GBR",
  "independent": true,
  "status": "officially-assigned",
  "unMember": true,
  "currencies": {
    "GBP": {
      "name": "British pound",
      "symbol": "£"
    }
  },
  "idd": {
    "root": "+4",
    "suffixes": ["4"]
  },
  "capital": ["London"],
  "altSpellings": ["GB", "UK", "Great Britain"],
  "region": "Europe",
  "subregion": "Northern Europe",
  "languages": {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  "translations": {
    "ara": {
      "official": "المملكة المتحدة لبريطانيا العظمى وايرلندا الشمالية",
      "common": "المملكة المتحدة"
    },
    "ces": {
      "official": "Spojené království Velké Británie a Severního Irska",
      "common": "Spojené království"
    },
    "cym": {
      "official": "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
      "common": "United Kingdom"
    },
    "deu": {
      "official": "Vereinigtes Königreich Großbritannien und Nordirland",
      "common": "Vereinigtes Königreich"
    },
    "est": {
      "official": "Suurbritannia ja Põhja-Iiri Ühendkuningriik",
      "common": "Suurbritannia"
    },
    "fin": {
      "official": "Ison-Britannian ja Pohjois-Irlannin yhdistynyt kuningaskunta",
      "common": "Yhdistynyt kuningaskunta"
    },
    "fra": {
      "official": "Royaume-Uni de Grande-Bretagne et d'Irlande du Nord",
      "common": "Royaume-Uni"
    },
    "hrv": {
      "official": "Ujedinjeno Kraljevstvo Velike Britanije i Sjeverne Irske",
      "common": "Ujedinjeno Kraljevstvo"
    },
    "hun": {
      "official": "Nagy-Britannia és Észak-Írország Egyesült Királysága",
      "common": "Egyesült Királyság"
    },
    "ita": {
      "official": "Regno Unito di Gran Bretagna e Irlanda del Nord",
      "common": "Regno Unito"
    },
    "jpn": {
      "official": "グレート·ブリテンおよび北アイルランド連合王国",
      "common": "イギリス"
    },
    "kor": {
      "official": "그레이트브리튼 북아일랜드 연합 왕국",
      "common": "영국"
    },
    "nld": {
      "official": "Verenigd Koninkrijk van Groot-Brittannië en Noord-Ierland",
      "common": "Verenigd Koninkrijk"
    },
    "per": {
      "official": "پادشاهی متحد بریتانیای کبیر و ایرلند شمالی",
      "common": "انگلیس"
    },
    "pol": {
      "official": "Zjednoczone Królestwo Wielkiej Brytanii i Irlandii Północnej",
      "common": "Zjednoczone Krłlestwo"
    },
    "por": {
      "official": "Reino Unido da Grã-Bretanha e Irlanda do Norte",
      "common": "Reino Unido"
    },
    "rus": {
      "official": "Соединенное Королевство Великобритании и Северной Ирландии",
      "common": "Великобритания"
    },
    "slk": {
      "official": "Spojené kráľovstvo Veľkej Británie a SevernéhoÌrska",
      "common": "Veľká Británia (Spojené kráľovstvo)"
    },
    "spa": {
      "official": "Reino Unido de Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte",
      "common": "Reino Unido"
    },
    "swe": {
      "official": "Förenade konungariket Storbritannien och Nordirland",
      "common": "Storbritannien"
    },
    "urd": {
      "official": "مملکتِ متحدہ برطانیہ عظمی و شمالی آئرلینڈ",
      "common": "مملکتِ متحدہ"
    },
    "zho": {
      "official": "大不列颠及北爱尔兰联合王国",
      "common": "英国"
    }
  },
  "latlng": [54, -2],
  "landlocked": false,
  "borders": ["IRL"],
  "area": 242900,
  "demonyms": {
    "eng": {
      "f": "British",
      "m": "British"
    },
    "fra": {
      "f": "Britannique",
      "m": "Britannique"
    }
  },
  "flag": "",
  "maps": {
    "googleMaps": "https://goo.gl/maps/FoDtc3UKMkFsXAjHA",
    "openStreetMaps": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62149"
  },
  "population": 67215293,
  "gini": {
    "2017": 35.1
  },
  "car": {
    "signs": ["GB"],
    "side": "left"
  },
  "timezones": ["UTC-08:00", "UTC-05:00", "UTC-04:00", "UTC-03:00", "UTC-02:00", "UTC", "UTC+01:00", "UTC+02:00", "UTC+06:00"],
  "continents": ["Europe"],
  "flags": {
    "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/gb.png",
    "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/gb.svg"
  },
  "coatOfArms": {
    "png": "https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/gb.png",
    "svg": "https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/gb.svg"
  },
  "startOfWeek": "monday",
  "capitalInfo": {
    "latlng": [51.5, -0.08]
  },
  "postalCode": {
    "format": "@# #@@|@## #@@|@@# #@@|@@## #@@|@#@ #@@|@@#@ #@@|GIR0AA",
    "regex": "^(([A-Z]\\d{2}[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]\\d{3}[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]{2}\\d{2}[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]{2}\\d{3}[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]\\d[A-Z]\\d[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]{2}\\d[A-Z]\\d[A-Z]{2})|(GIR0AA))$"
  }
}
```

I then want to capture  the name of the currency (in this case GBP) into a variable so I can then use this to make a call to another API to get the current exchange rate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the object's property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260308/getting-the-objects-property-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand it correctly, but something like this?

```js
const data = {"name":{"common":"United Kingdom","official":"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland","nativeName":{"eng":{"official":"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland","common":"United Kingdom"}}},"tld":[".uk"],"cca2":"GB","ccn3":"826","cca3":"GBR","cioc":"GBR","independent":true,"status":"officially-assigned","unMember":true,"currencies":{"GBP":{"name":"British pound","symbol":"£"}},"idd":{"root":"+4","suffixes":["4"]},"capital":["London"],"altSpellings":["GB","UK","Great Britain"],"region":"Europe","subregion":"Northern Europe","languages":{"eng":"English"},"translations":{"ara":{"official":"المملكة المتحدة لبريطانيا العظمى وايرلندا الشمالية","common":"المملكة المتحدة"},"ces":{"official":"Spojené království Velké Británie a Severního Irska","common":"Spojené království"},"cym":{"official":"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland","common":"United Kingdom"},"deu":{"official":"Vereinigtes Königreich Großbritannien und Nordirland","common":"Vereinigtes Königreich"},"est":{"official":"Suurbritannia ja Põhja-Iiri Ühendkuningriik","common":"Suurbritannia"},"fin":{"official":"Ison-Britannian ja Pohjois-Irlannin yhdistynyt kuningaskunta","common":"Yhdistynyt kuningaskunta"},"fra":{"official":"Royaume-Uni de Grande-Bretagne et d'Irlande du Nord","common":"Royaume-Uni"},"hrv":{"official":"Ujedinjeno Kraljevstvo Velike Britanije i Sjeverne Irske","common":"Ujedinjeno Kraljevstvo"},"hun":{"official":"Nagy-Britannia és Észak-Írország Egyesült Királysága","common":"Egyesült Királyság"},"ita":{"official":"Regno Unito di Gran Bretagna e Irlanda del Nord","common":"Regno Unito"},"jpn":{"official":"グレート·ブリテンおよび北アイルランド連合王国","common":"イギリス"},"kor":{"official":"그레이트브리튼 북아일랜드 연합 왕국","common":"영국"},"nld":{"official":"Verenigd Koninkrijk van Groot-Brittannië en Noord-Ierland","common":"Verenigd Koninkrijk"},"per":{"official":"پادشاهی متحد بریتانیای کبیر و ایرلند شمالی","common":"انگلیس"},"pol":{"official":"Zjednoczone Królestwo Wielkiej Brytanii i Irlandii Północnej","common":"Zjednoczone Krłlestwo"},"por":{"official":"Reino Unido da Grã-Bretanha e Irlanda do Norte","common":"Reino Unido"},"rus":{"official":"Соединенное Королевство Великобритании и Северной Ирландии","common":"Великобритания"},"slk":{"official":"Spojené kráľovstvo Veľkej Británie a SevernéhoÌrska","common":"Veľká Británia (Spojené kráľovstvo)"},"spa":{"official":"Reino Unido de Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte","common":"Reino Unido"},"swe":{"official":"Förenade konungariket Storbritannien och Nordirland","common":"Storbritannien"},"urd":{"official":"مملکتِ متحدہ برطانیہ عظمی و شمالی آئرلینڈ","common":"مملکتِ متحدہ"},"zho":{"official":"大不列颠及北爱尔兰联合王国","common":"英国"}},"latlng":[54,-2],"landlocked":false,"borders":["IRL"],"area":242900,"demonyms":{"eng":{"f":"British","m":"British"},"fra":{"f":"Britannique","m":"Britannique"}},"flag":"","maps":{"googleMaps":"https://goo.gl/maps/FoDtc3UKMkFsXAjHA","openStreetMaps":"https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62149"},"population":67215293,"gini":{"2017":35.1},"car":{"signs":["GB"],"side":"left"},"timezones":["UTC-08:00","UTC-05:00","UTC-04:00","UTC-03:00","UTC-02:00","UTC","UTC+01:00","UTC+02:00","UTC+06:00"],"continents":["Europe"],"flags":{"png":"https://flagcdn.com/w320/gb.png","svg":"https://flagcdn.com/gb.svg"},"coatOfArms":{"png":"https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/gb.png","svg":"https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/gb.svg"},"startOfWeek":"monday","capitalInfo":{"latlng":[51.5,-0.08]},"postalCode":{"format":"@# #@@|@## #@@|@@# #@@|@@## #@@|@#@ #@@|@@#@ #@@|GIR0AA","regex":"^(([A-Z]\\d{2}[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]\\d{3}[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]{2}\\d{2}[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]{2}\\d{3}[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]\\d[A-Z]\\d[A-Z]{2})|([A-Z]{2}\\d[A-Z]\\d[A-Z]{2})|(GIR0AA))$"}}


let currency = Object.keys(data.currencies)[0]
console.log(currency)
```

Answer (score 0):

var json = JSON.parse(data);

var currencyNameGBP = json.currencies.GBP.name;