# Get component property name in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to get property name of angular component?

```
@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  myProperty: string[] = [];
...

for example:
getName(this.myProperty) // => "myProperty";
```

I have tried Object.keys(this.myProperty), but it returns []

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the object's property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260308/getting-the-objects-property-name)

Comment: This exactly is not possible. You can zty `Objects.keys(this)`. But that will always return an array with all properties inside a object. `Object.keys(this.myProperty)` returns `[]` because it returns the properties of its value. And `[]` has no own properties.